# Tricky Android Login Screen

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I  am working on a login screen for an app

I have followed this tutorial to the letter

http://javapapers.com/android/beautiful-android-login-screen-design-tutorial/
(not being lazy by not copying in the source, just thought it was better to add  the link to credit someone else for the hard work)

there was a couple of permissions missing from the tutorial, which i added but to no avail

i have also increased my Api from 15 to 16, this also did not work

i am receiving the following error

```
05-11 19:23:21.240  28766-28766/? E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.example.alex.jsonparsegridview [ userId:0 | appId:10263 ]
05-11 19:23:21.490  28766-28792/com.example.alex.jsonparsegridview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.alex.jsonparsegridview, PID: 28766
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10263 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PROFILE.
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:413)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:477)
            at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:65)
            at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:43)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing [READ_PROFILE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PROFILE) permission

Answer (score 2):

Add the below permission to your manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
```